# Electron-Builder does not copy node_modules into my application

Tags: npm, electron, electron-builder

I have an electron app with the following structure

```
- dist
| - index.html
| - node_modules
| - nm (is an exact copy of node_modules)
- package.json
| ...
```

if I refer to the node modules in my index.html as `node_modules/module` the app won't find the module if built with the build command from electron-builder. But if I change that line in my index.html to `nm/module` it is perfectly willing to load it.

It seems to me that electron-builder isn't copying node_modules into the application, but I can't see why it would do that. Is it excluding all folders named node_modules and how can I fix this?

Comment: I have a similar issue, did you manage to solve it? Which executable format did you use?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually chose which node modules to copy by using the files property in electron builder.

In the *build* property use the property *files* in your package.json and then do the following:

```
"files": [
            "node_modules/electron-dl/**/*",
            "node_modules/electron-updater/**/*",
            "node_modules/builder-util-runtime/**/*",
            "node_modules/graceful-fs/**/*",
            "node_modules/lazy-val/**/*",
            "node_modules/lodash.escaperegexp/**/*",
            "node_modules/lodash.isequal/**/*",
            "node_modules/sax/**/*",
            "node_modules/argparse/**/*",
            "node_modules/debug/**/*",
            "node_modules/fs-extra/**/*",
            "node_modules/jsonfile/**/*",
            "node_modules/js-yaml/**/*",
            "node_modules/lodash.escaperegexp/**/*",
            "node_modules/lodash.isequal/**/*",
            "node_modules/lru-cache/**/*",
            "node_modules/ms/**/*",
            "node_modules/rxjs/**/*",
            "node_modules/semver/**/*",
            "node_modules/tslib/**/*",
            "node_modules/typed-emitter/**/*",
            "node_modules/universalify/**/*",
            "node_modules/yallist/**/*",
            "node_modules/electron-log/**/*",
            "!**/node_modules/*/{CHANGELOG.md,README.md,README,readme.md,readme}",
            "!**/node_modules/*/{test,__tests__,tests,powered-test,example,examples}"
        ],
```

Note, this will then only copy over the specified node modules. To copy over other files you have to specify them.

Also, if you want to see if the node modules are there you can set `asar: false` (in build property) and then you can check inside resources->app->node_modules