# Electron builder not copying my dist/node_modules directory in the right place

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I've got one node application which I'm already launching with Electron. Now, I want to package it with electron-builder, but I'm dealing with such an strange behaviour. Usually, when I build my application, a dist folder gets generated, containing all the transpiled javascript files and also the package.json. Then, I have to run `npm i --production` again there to set up my production dependencies. So what I want electron-builder to do is to copy exactly the dist directory as it is once everything is installed:

```
electron-builder build --linux AppImage
```

This is my package.json related config:

```
  "main": "dist/app.js",
  "build": {
    "appId": "my.app",
    "files": [
      "dist/**/*"
    ]
  },
```

I guess that with this configuration I'm telling it to copy the dist directory and its contents. The AppImage file gets built and if I unzip it, I can see a `resources` dir gets created inside, containing one `app.asar` file. If I extract the asar content, I can see `node_modules` gets placed at the same level than `dist`, and not inside of it!! So I have:

```
  AppImage
  -- resources
  ---- app.asar
  ------ node_modules
  ------ dist (everything except node_modules)
```

When I launch the application it obviously complains of not finding the `node_modules`. [The docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents) say there's some default files pattern which can take precedence of what user has defined...

I also have tried:

```
"files": {
  "from": "dist",
  "to": "dist",
  "filter": ["**/*"]
}
```

And seems not being able to find the `package.json` file.

Somebody asked [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041326/electron-builder-does-not-copy-node-modules-into-my-application) years ago, with no answer. Any help please?

Comment: Are you packing via cli or API ? I had same problem via API and the example i copied from [link]https://www.electron.build/api/programmatic-usage 
` beforeBuild: async (context) => {
    const { appDir, electronVersion, arch } = context
    await electronRebuild.rebuild({ buildPath: appDir, electronVersion, arch })
    return false
  },` was the issue. removed it and now it works.

Comment: Hello @SaurabhSingh, I'm doing it via CLI. Quite strange..

Comment: try
"build": {
    "files": "./dist/**/**.*",

Comment: Can you post the error after application launch which indicates it cannot find the folder `node_modules`. Also, are you using `electron-packager`? At this moment in time, it sounds like a (hopefully simple) folder scope issue.

Comment: @SaurabhSingh tried that config, still the same behaviour..

Comment: @midnight-coding, I'm not using electron-packager, but electron-builder instead. The error basically is the same as when trying to launch the application without the node_modules folder: typeorm dependency not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the way to do it, I had to tweak the configuration with a property that I found in the [docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration.html): `includeSubNodeModules`, which defaults to `false` and seems to include the *node_modules* subfolders in the output. Also I had to explicitly omit the root *node_modules* folder since I don't want it in the output.

```
  "build": {
    "appId": "myApplication",
    "files": [
      "dist/**/*",
      "!node_modules"
    ],
    "includeSubNodeModules": true
  },
```